# Android compile error

Tags: android, c++

I need your help compiling AOSP ICS (Android 4.0.4).
I stucked in an error for compile a .cpp file and a .h file.
That's the error log:

```
In file included from hardware/qcom/display/libgralloc/framebuffer.cpp:53:
hardware/qcom/display/libqcomui/qcom_ui.h: In member function 'void QCBaseLayer::setS3DComposeFormat(int32_t)':
hardware/qcom/display/libqcomui/qcom_ui.h:174: error: 'HWC_HINT_DRAW_S3D_SIDE_BY_SIDE' was not declared in this scope
hardware/qcom/display/libqcomui/qcom_ui.h:176: error: 'HWC_HINT_DRAW_S3D_TOP_BOTTOM' was not declared in this scope
hardware/qcom/display/libgralloc/framebuffer.cpp: In function 'int mapFrameBufferLocked(private_module_t*)':
hardware/qcom/display/libgralloc/framebuffer.cpp:870: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
hardware/qcom/display/libgralloc/framebuffer.cpp:871: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
hardware/qcom/display/libgralloc/framebuffer.cpp: In function 'int fb_device_open(const hw_module_t*, const char*, hw_device_t**)':
hardware/qcom/display/libgralloc/framebuffer.cpp:994: error: 'struct framebuffer_device_t' has no member named 'lockBuffer'
hardware/qcom/display/libgralloc/framebuffer.cpp:995: error: 'struct framebuffer_device_t' has no member named 'perform'
hardware/qcom/display/libgralloc/framebuffer.cpp:1011: error: 'struct framebuffer_device_t' has no member named 'numFramebuffers'
make: *** [out/target/product/gio/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/gralloc.msm7x27_intermediates/framebuffer.o] Error 1
```

So? These are the file codes:
- **framebuffer.cpp**: [AOSP ICS 4.0.4 - /hardware/display/libgralloc/framebuffer.cpp](http://pastebin.com/jVKchNSE)
- **qcom_ui.h**: [AOSP ICS 4.0.4 - /hardware/qcom/display/libqcomui/qcom_ui.h](http://pastebin.com/SVhHrQWY)